# Getting Jquery-UI slider value while sliding

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag, uislider, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

i got a jquery ui slider and i want to show the value of the slider in a tooltip, (in handler of the slider).
so far im getting the value when the slider stops, but i want the tooltip to update the value when the slider is dragged. 
is there a way to get jquery UI slider current position, not the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `slide` function

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
    slide: function(event,ui){
        $('#value').text(ui.value);    
    }
});
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/jcMu8/

Comment: works like a charm... i haved trouble to target the element that takes the tooltip value but once i did it "salio arando" like we say here.
`slide: function(event,ui){
        $('.ui-slider-handle').attr("data-original-title",ui.value);    
    }`

thx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

write a jquery function that is triggered by the slider slide event that replaces the value of the tool tip.

`slide: function(event, ui){
       //replace value

}`